# Get specific content with CURL on all links in a page (like a spider)

Tags: php, curl

I'm coding a little app that start from a URL and look on all links in that specific page.
Next, it will go on all links and scrape the contents but will show only a specific content (numbers with 10 or more char).
This is my code but it retrieve blank page, what is wrong?

```
//I

$url = 'http://xxx.xxx';
$str = file_get_contents($url);
$original_file = file_get_contents($url);
$stripped_file = strip_tags($original_file, "<a>");
preg_match_all("/<a(?:[^>]*)href=\"([^\"]*)\"(?:[^>]*)>(?:[^<]*)<\/a>/is", $stripped_file, $matches);
$links = $matches[1];
//print_r($links);

//F

//F
$count = count($links);
for($i=0;$i<=$count;$i++)
{
  //I
  $curl_handle=curl_init();
  curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,$links[$i]);
  curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
  curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.7.3) Gecko/20041001 Firefox/0.10.1');
  $query = curl_exec($curl_handle);
  curl_close($curl_handle);
  preg_match_all('/\b3\d+/', $query, $matches2);
  $numbers = $matches2[0];  
  $count = 0;
  foreach($numbers as $value) {
    if(strlen((string)$value) >= 10) echo '<br><br>[' . $count++ . "]" . $value; 
  }
  //F   
}
//F
```

Comment: I'd not init a fresh curl instance on every request. Use the benefit of `Keep-Alive` and reuse the curl session.

Comment: I noticed you don't have any debugging implemented. [Enable error reporting](http://blog.flowl.info/2013/enable-display-php-errors/) and try again..

Answer (score 0):

**Issue#1**: Your html can have urls like following from where it is picking the links as `/home/test.php` without the base `http://www.example.com/`. So before requesting with curl, print it on screen or browser and check what it is.

```
<a href="/home/test.php">link</a>
```

**Issue#2**: `2` seconds for `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT` can prove less for you. So try increasing this value.

```
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
```

If the problem still persists, please show us a sample page link. And a sample internal link for which you get the blank response.